# About insertion sort and especially why it's said that copy is much faster than swap?

Tags: java, algorithms, sorting

From [Lafore's "Data Structures and Algorithms in Java"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672324539):
(about insertion sort (which uses copy + shift instead of swap (used in bubble and selection sort)))

> However, a copy isn’t as time-consuming as a swap, so for random data
>   this algo- rithm runs twice as fast as the bubble sort and faster than
>   the selectionsort.

Additionally, the author doesn't mention how time consuming shift is.

It seems that copying is the simplest pointer assignment operation. While swap is 3 pointer assignment operations, which don't take much time. Further, shift of N elements is N pointer assignment operations.

Can someone explain this seeming inconsistency?

Comment: To provide another view on swaps in terms of general computing and not just Java, for example on x86 native code there exists a `XCHG` instruction which effectively swaps or *exchanges* two values within a single clock cycle. I am not sure if Java Bytecode has such an instruction though, or if there's a Java VM implementation which could delegate a swap to a single `XCHG` instruction on x86 - but at least I think there's nothing which would prevent that from happening - which would mean that a swap operation would actually be just as fast as overwriting a variable with another.

Comment: AFAIK, Java 5 has 'compareAndSet' atomic operation (which is used in concurrent applications), so I believe that it can optimize swap to be a single instruction. Because of this I'm even more confused about what author says.

Answer (score 2):

> a copy isn’t as time-consuming as a swap

Let's compare a copy to a swap:

```
int[] a = ...
int idx = ...

// copy:
a[idx] = a[idx + 1];

// swap:
int temp = a[idx];
a[idx] = a[idx + 1];
a[idx + 1] = temp;
```

Swap allocates a temporary variable performs and three copies - one from the array to the temporary variable, one from one index at the array to another, and one from the temporary variable back to the array.  Therefore a swap is at least 3 times as expensive as a copy.

Shifting elements in an array (as opposed to shifting bits in a primitive integer type) is expensive because it is repeated copying:

```
for (int i = shiftEnd - 1; i >= shiftStart; i--) {
  a[i + 1] = a[i];
}
```

You can see here that when (shiftEnd - shiftStart) > 3 a shift will perform more copy operations than a swap.

Let's look at the same example with an array of pointers to objects instead of primitive ints:

```
Object[] a = ...

// copy the pointer to an object from one array element to another
a[idx] = a[idx + 1]; 

// swap the pointer to an object between array elements
Object temp = a[idx];
a[idx] = a[idx + 1];
a[idx + 1] = temp;
```

You will notice that these operations are exactly the same whether dealing with primitives or objects.  The List version is more expensive due to the method-call overhead of accessing the list.  Most List implementations use multiple arrays to allow resizing of the list which is more expensive than using a single, fixed-length primitive array.

Comment: While copying is faster than swapping for primitives, or for .NET or Java heap-object references, in languages like C++ a swap operation may sometimes be much *faster* than a copy.  Further, while the list-related interfaces in Java and .NET don't happen to support a `Swap` operation, a method to swap two items in a list could be used without the caller having to know the type in question, which would allow code which can sort a `ReadablePermutableList<Animal>` to also work on a `ReadablePermutableList<SiameseCat>`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't doing one swap/copy you are doing roughly `n log(n)` swaps/copies. So you get `3n log(n)` assignments for swapping or `n log(n) + n` assignments for copy.

Comment: Well, if compare bubble sort and insertion sort, in case of bubble sort we're doing n^2 swaps (n*(n-1)/2 to be precise, but for big O notation it doesn't matter), right? in case of insertion sort we're doing n^2 copies. So in first case we're doing 9n^2 copies (if 3 copies = 1 swap), and in second case we're doing n^2 copies. So anyway, for big O notation, we're doing same amount of copies and because copy as I believe is very fast 9n^2 is almost the same as n^2. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, big O notation ignores constant factors.  Thus your 9n^2 algorithm will be 9 times as expensive as your n^2 *for every* sufficiently large value of *n* even though they have the same big O notation.  Big O only cares that they grow at the same rate as *n* increases, even if one algorithm is always more expensive than the other.  Maybe you will some day run on a machine that has a swap operation that's faster than it's copy operation?  Big O doesn't care (Honey Badger Don't Care!).  It's only interested in growth as *n* increases.